# Why is bind asking for this extra parameter in my zone file?

Tags: linux, bind

I'm creating a zone file for a fake root because this is a closed network with no Internet access. I've created the following zone file but for some reason, bind is requiring an extra parameter; specifically, the 234324.

```
$TTL    300
.       IN      SOA      ns.fakeroot.com (
                               20111205
                               1800
                               90
                               604800
                               86400
                               234324
                         )
        IN      NS       ns
ns      IN      A        127.0.0.1
```

My other zones files don't have that parameter. When I take that value out, the server fails to start with the following error:

```
dns_rdata_fromtext: root.zone:7 near eol: unexpected end of input
zone ./IN: loading from master file root.zone failed: unexpected end of input
```

Why do I need that extra value?

Comment: Note: all zone files should end with new line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't look like a valid SOA. You are missing the email address so I suspect 20111205 is being treated as such.

```
; zone file for example.com
$TTL 2d    ; 172800 secs default TTL for zone
$ORIGIN example.com.
@             IN      SOA   ns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
                        2003080800 ; se = serial number
                        12h        ; ref = refresh
                        15m        ; ret = update retry
                        3w         ; ex = expiry
                        3h         ; min = minimum
                        )
```